# Strange page rendering in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have the following code in the view of an application I am developing using the codeigniter framework

```
<?php foreach($query->result_array() as $row){ ?>
        <tr>
        <?php echo form_open('MainController/AttendanceSet');?>
            <input type="hidden" name="child_nric" value="<?php echo $row['child_nric']; ?>"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="teachernric" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="progcode" value="<?php echo $program; ?>"/>


            <td><?php echo $row['child_nric']; ?></td>
            <td>    
                <select name="attendance">                  
                    <option value="1" selected="<?php if($selected==1) echo "selected"; ?>">Present</option>
                    <option value="0" selected="<?php if($selected==0) echo "selected"; ?>">Absent</option>
                </select>

            </td>
            <td> <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></form></td>
        </tr>

        <?php } ?>
```

Have made edit to the code based on the answers below now it is like this

```
<?php foreach($query->result_array() as $row){ ?>
        <tr>
        <?php echo form_open('MainController/AttendanceSet');?>
            <input type="hidden" name="child_nric" value="<?php echo $row['child_nric']; ?>"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="teachernric" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="progcode" value="<?php echo $program; ?>"/>


            <td><?php echo $row['child_nric']; ?></td>
            <td>    
                <select name="attendance">                  
                    <option value="1" selected="<?php if($selected==1) echo "selected"; ?>">Present</option>
                    <option value="0" selected="<?php if($selected==0) echo "selected"; ?>">Absent</option>
                </select>

            </td>
            <td> <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></td>
        </tr>

        <?php echo form_close();}   ?>
```

**But the output is still the same**

However when the view is loaded, the code comes out like this

```
<tr>
        <form action="http://sms-dev.anovatesoft.com/index.php/MainController/AttendanceSet" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8"></form>
            <input type="hidden" name="child_nric" value="A12">
            <input type="hidden" name="teachernric" value="T001">
            <input type="hidden" name="progcode" value="FEE001">


            <td>A12</td>
            <td>    
                <select name="attendance">                  
                    <option value="1" selected="">Present</option>
                    <option value="0" selected="">Absent</option>
                </select>

            </td>
            <td> <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></td>
        </tr>
```

Notice the difference in the `</from>` position? In my code I have it after the submit button but when it renders it closes just after the `<form>` opens making the form useless as I am not able to submit it.
What is the reason behind this strange behavior? And how do I fix it?

---

**The View**

```
<?php
$this->load->helper('form');
?>

<script>
    function ListView(){
        //if($("#id").val() != "0"){
        var formURL = "<?php echo base_url();?>MainController/Attendance/"+$("#program").val();
        $.post(formURL).done(function(data){$("#body_view_paste").html(data); });

    }

    function fire(){
        alert("I have been fired");
    }
</script>

<div align="center">
    <table align="center"  style="max-width:80%">
    <tr>
            <td>Program</td>
            <td>
               <select id="program" name="program" onchange="ListView()">
           <option value="0">Select</option>            
                <?php 
                $nricno = $_SESSION['username'];
                $sql = "SELECT distinct programs.activities, programs.progcode FROM events
        LEFT JOIN programs ON programs.progcode=events.progcode WHERE events.teacher_nric='$nricno'";

        $activities = $this->db->query($sql);
        foreach($activities->result_array() as $row){?>

                            <option value="<?php echo $row['progcode'];?>"><?php echo $row['activities'];?></option>  
                   <?php } ?>
            </select>

            </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
 </div>
 <div>
 <?php if(isset($program)){ 
 $selected=3;
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT child_nric FROM child_reg_prog WHERE progcode = '$program'");
                ?>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>NRIC NO</td>
                <td>Attendance</td>     
        <td>Action</td>
            </tr>
    </thead>

        <?php foreach($query->result_array() as $row){ ?>
        <tr>
        <?php echo form_open('MainController/AttendanceSet');?>
            <input type="hidden" name="child_nric" value="<?php echo $row['child_nric']; ?>"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="teachernric" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="progcode" value="<?php echo $program; ?>"/>


            <td><?php echo $row['child_nric']; ?></td>
            <td>    
                <select name="attendance">                  
                    <option value="1" selected="<?php if($selected==1) echo "selected"; ?>">Present</option>
                    <option value="0" selected="<?php if($selected==0) echo "selected"; ?>">Absent</option>
                </select>

            </td>
            <td> <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></td>
        </tr>

        <?php echo form_close();}   ?>      

    </table>    
    <?php } ?>
 </div>
```

**The Controller part**

```
public function Attendance($program = "")
    {
        $this->main_model->pagePermissions("Attendance");
        if ($program == "") {
            $this->load->view('Attendance');
        } else {
            $data['program'] = $program;
            $this->load->view('Attendance', $data);
        }
    }
    public function AttendanceSet()
    {
        $child_nric = $_POST['child_nric'];
        $attendance = $_POST['attendance'];
        $teachernric = $_POST['teachernric'];
        $progcode = $_POST['progcode'];
        $ispresent="No";
        if($attendance==1)
        {
            $ispresent="Yes";
        }
        $this->load->model("Attendance_model");
        $this->Attendance_model->insert($progcode, $childnric, $teachernric, $ispresent);       

        $this->load->view('Attendance');
    }
```

**The model part**

```
<?php   if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');


class Attendance_model extends CI_Model {

    function __construct()
    {
        // Call the Model constructor
        parent::__construct();
    }
    function insert($progcode, $childnric, $teachernric, $ispresent)
    {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO attendence (progcode, childnric, teachernric, ispresent ) VALUES (?,?,?,?) "; 
        $query = $this->db->query($sql, array($progcode, $childnric, $teachernric, $ispresent));        
    }


}
?>
```

Comment: Have you close your `form` tag???

Comment: @saty please look into the code posted above you can clearly see the form tag closing after the submit button can I not use it this way?

Comment: and looking at this code makes me remember why I stopped using CodeIgniter and learned to love Laravel

Comment: @AndrewBrown I love cakephp but office .... *sighs*

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<?php foreach($query->result_array() as $row){ ?>
    <?php echo form_open('MainController/AttendanceSet');?>
    <tr>
        <input type="hidden" name="child_nric" value="<?php echo $row['child_nric']; ?>"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="teachernric" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="progcode" value="<?php echo $program; ?>"/>


        <td><?php echo $row['child_nric']; ?></td>
        <td>    
            <select name="attendance">                  
                <option value="1" selected="<?php if($selected==1) echo "selected"; ?>">Present</option>
                <option value="0" selected="<?php if($selected==0) echo "selected"; ?>">Absent</option>
            </select>

        </td>
        <td> <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></td>
    </tr>
    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
    <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Both of the below statements should come outside the `foreach` loop

```
<?php echo form_open('MainController/AttendanceSet');?>
 <?php echo form_close(); ?>// you need to close it
```